# How can I most efficiently deduce Renaissance Technologies' changes?

Tags: data

[The Motley Fool](https://www.fool.com/investing/2019/05/29/2-billionaires-just-bought-aurora-cannabis-stock-s.aspx), [Nasdaq](https://www.nasdaq.com/articles/investing-guru-jim-simons-pours-money-into-these-3-cannabis-stocks-2019-11-15) and [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/investing-guru-jim-simons-pours-151631510.html) all were able to deduce RenTech's purchases of cannabis stocks.

I can see RenTech's quarterly reports on [EDGAR](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001037389&type=&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=100), but they don't list changes. How can I deduce the changes most productively, without manually and unproductively comparing each stock holding?

I'm uneducated in computer science and programming; I don't understand much of [Is there an API to parse SEC filings on EDGAR?](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-an-API-to-parse-SEC-filings-on-EDGAR).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end you have to compare current quarterly holdings to those reported a quarter ago. You can try to buy this data, hire someone who can do it for you programmatically, or figure out how to do it yourself.